# My android device has 8 Cores CPU but in the Power Profile file I get only 4 cores

Tags: android, energy, cpu-cores

I'm using Android device with 8 cores CPU,
I want to analyze energy consumption of my device using its PowerProfile file,
I'm using these command lines to get the power profile of my device

```
java -jar apktool_2.2.2.jar if framework-res.apk
java -jar apktool_2.2.2.jar d framework-res.apk
```

here is a part of the power_profile.xml I got :

```
<array name="cpu.clusters.cores">
    <value>4</value>
</array>
<array name="cpu.speeds.cluster0">
    <value>850000</value>
    <value>918000</value>
    <value>987000</value>
    <value>1056000</value>
    <value>1125000</value>
    <value>1216000</value>
    <value>1308000</value>
    <value>1400000</value>
    <value>1466000</value>
    <value>1533000</value>
    <value>1633000</value>
    <value>1700000</value>
    <value>1767000</value>
    <value>1834000</value>
    <value>1917000</value>
    <value>2001000</value>
</array>
<array name="cpu.active.cluster0">
    <value>9.3</value>
    <value>9.3</value>
    <value>10.6</value>
    <value>11.6</value>
    <value>13.3</value>
    <value>15.0</value>
    <value>17.2</value>
    <value>20.2</value>
    <value>22.8</value>
    <value>26.3</value>
    <value>27.4</value>
    <value>29.7</value>
    <value>30.2</value>
    <value>32.1</value>
    <value>33.9</value>
    <value>38.5</value>
</array>
<item name="cpu.idle">4.1</item>
```

Can anyone help me to know why I get only 4 cores cpu in the power profile file ?

Comment: Sometimes (usually?), 8-core devices only use 4 cores at once. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_big.LITTLE for example.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any idea how can I get a power profile file that contains the 8 cores as it is shown in this example :
`<array name="cpu.clusters.cores">
        <value>4</value>
        <value>4</value>
    </array>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all the actual ***framework-res.apk*** and so ***power_profile.xml*** file location depends on the manufacturer, so  first of all it is better to find the correct location. Values from the default path that is noted in android documentation [here](https://source.android.com/docs/core/power/values) may be overridden. Try to check within next possible paths:

> /system/vendor
>
> /product/overlay

or use find to check if your device has some other potential location for ***framework-res.apk***

Secondly, as providing a proper ***power_profie.xml*** file is a responsibility of manufacturer, he may didn`t provided all the information. Although there is a BatteryStats service which I think after some time levels out the lack of power_profile (not sure).